# CSS stylesheet : @Media setting in between 768px-992px

Tags: html, css, media-queries, stylesheet

On my responsive Opencart site, when resizing our page between the widths 768px and 992px our logo pushes down and doesn't align.

I can fix this by making the top margin -23px. This of course breaks it out of this range.

**Can you set a media screen range in CSS so a setting is applied between 768px and 992px only?**

Our default CSS code
 #logo {
    margin: -30px 0 -2px -30px;

Comment: What's the rule with having multiple answers of exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed!

```
@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
    #logo { 
       // margin code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this..

```
@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  #logo { 
   // Margin value here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
    #logo { 
        margin: -30px 0 -2px -30px;
    }
}
```